# Problem with integral$\int_A\frac{x+y}{(1+(x+y)^2)^2}dxdy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I have integral
$$
\int_A\frac{x+y}{(1+(x+y)^2)^2}dxdy
$$
$A=\{(x,y):x>0,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$

First:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x+y}{(1+(x+y)^2)^2}dxdy={1\over 2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dy}{1+y^2}={\pi\over2}$$

Second try:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x+y}{(1+(x+y)^2)^2}dydx=\int_{0}^{\infty}0dx=0$$

So should I conclude that Lebesgue integral does not exist?

Comment: Would you mind explaining how did you evaluate the integrals in "first, second try" ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Which step do you have in mind? The last one, like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dy}{1+y^2}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dy}{1+y^2}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dy}{1+y^2}=2\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}arctana=\pi/2$ in the first case?

Comment: No, that one is completely trivial. The first one, in fact.

Comment: @DonAntonio I started to think about. Forget about what I wrote for a moment. If this is Lebesgue integral, then I should determine first when function under integral is above 0 and when it is below. Then evaluate these values separately and make sum of it. Right?

Comment: This integral seems to be 0 if properly evaluated. Just take $x=x_1+x_2,\  y=x_1-x_2$ and put $N$ instead of $\infty$ with the idea to take the limit $N\rightarrow\infty$ at the end of the computation. This computation yields 0. On the other hand, if you use a symbolic tool on a computer you will realize that this is able to yield 0 only if the proper sequence of integrations is taken (otherwise you get infinity), casting doubts on the existence of it. I do not know if this is just a limitation of the tool.

Comment: @Sek I can't understand why you "should", but that would be a way to do it, yes. Yet the real problem here is to **actually evaluate** the integral, whether given scalar fucntion is above or under zero.

Comment: @DonAntonio: we cannot "actually evaluate" the integral, because the integrand function does not belong to $L^1(A)$: $$\iint(\ldots)\,dx\,dy\neq \iint(\ldots)\,dy\,dx$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Oh, I could agree to that...yet the OP wrote what he did and that's why I asked him: how did he arrive to those results? Also, are you sure that a two-variable function is Lebesque integral iff  $\;\iint dydx=\iint dxdy\;\;?$ I really am not sure in this...

Comment: @DonAntonio I used Fubini theorem. The problem with my approach was that function is neither positive and measurable nor integrable, therefore Fubini thorem is not applicable. If it is applicable then order of integration doesn't change result.

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk I still can't see how you got zero and $\;\cfrac\pi2\;$ respectively...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the comments indicate that there is still a bit of confusion about what is going on, so I'm just going to add a bit more detail to the previous answer.

We can calculate the two iterated integrals as follows. For the first integral, the substitution $u=1+(x+y)^2$ gives $du=2(x+y)dx$ and
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(x+y)}{(1+(x+y)^2)^2}du dy=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int_{1+y^2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^2}du dy=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+y^2}dy=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+y^2}\;.$$
The last integral is evaluated as $\lim_{x\to \infty} tan^{-1}(x)=\pi/2$. The other integral is slightly more nuanced. For each $x$, the inner integral of the iterated integral can be evaluated via the same $u$-substitution. This will lead to the improper Riemann integral 
$$\lim_{M\to -\infty}\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_{1+(x+M)^2}^{1+(x+N)^2}\frac{1}{u^2}=0\;.$$
Thus, the iterated integral must be zero. The issue here of course is that Fubini's theorem does not apply. In fact, Fubini's theorem for $\sigma$-finite measure spaces implies that since the two iterated integrals do not agree, the function $f(x,y)=\frac{(x+y)}{(1+(x+y)^2)^2}$ cannot be in $L^1(A)$ (whenever the improper Riemann integral is finite it agrees with the Lesbesgue integral).

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Assuming that $f(x,y)=\frac{(x+y)}{(1+(x+y)^2)^2}\in L^1(A)$,
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,y)\,dy\,dx \tag{1}$$
has to hold, but the LHS of $(1)$ is zero while the RHS is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, hence $f\not\in L^1(A)$.